# Drawing smooth lines with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to draw lines with flutter using a Custom painter. i.e https://medium.com/flutter-community/drawing-in-flutter-using-custompainter-307a9f1c21f8

How can I make the lines drawling by user smooth?

Comment: What do you mean.. "smooth"?

Comment: You can see the first image in this link https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/cartography/smooth-line.htm  where the blue line is original and red like is smoothed line.

Comment: Did you managed to solve your issue? I'm facing a similar problem

Answer (score 9):

To draw smooth line path you can use `.cubicTo()` method of Path. It applies cubic Bezier interpolation. Here is code example of smooth line painter:

```dart
class SmoothLinePainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Color lineColor;
  final List<double> values;

  SmoothLinePainter(this.lineColor, this.values);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = lineColor
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 1;
    final path = Path();

    final yMin = values.reduce(min);
    final yMax = values.reduce(max);
    final yHeight = yMax - yMin;
    final xAxisStep = size.width / values.length;
    var xValue = 0.0;
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      final value = values[i];
      final yValue = yHeight == 0
          ? (0.5 * size.height)
          : ((yMax - value) / yHeight) * size.height;
      if (xValue == 0) {
        path.moveTo(xValue, yValue);
      } else {
        final previousValue = values[i - 1];
        final xPrevious = xValue - xAxisStep;
        final yPrevious = yHeight == 0
            ? (0.5 * size.height)
            : ((yMax - previousValue) / yHeight) * size.height;
        final controlPointX = xPrevious + (xValue - xPrevious) / 2;
        // HERE is the main line of code making your line smooth
        path.cubicTo(
            controlPointX, yPrevious, controlPointX, yValue, xValue, yValue);
      }
      xValue += xAxisStep;
    }
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(_LineChartPainter old) =>
      old.lineColor != lineColor && old.values != values;
}
```

And here is two images showing difference between using `.lineTo()` and `.cubicTo()` methods:

1. path.lineTo(...)

[image: .lineTo()]

2. path.cubicTo(...)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I made a blog on how to make this feature, I hope it helps you.

It describes how to get rid of the weird-looking lines when drawing and also how to implement erase and undo feature as well.

Blog:

https://ivanstajcer.medium.com/flutter-drawing-erasing-and-undo-with-custompainter-6d00fec2bbc2

If you are not interested in all of that I will tell you quick summary of two solutions, one I found online and one I made:

1. Use the list of offsets and draw a line or a curve between them and also draw a circle on every offset. But this is not performance good and it will give you a bad UX in the long run.
2. You can read about this in the blog, divide all lines into objects and store a Path for each line, as well as a list of Offsets. Then draw the path by calling canvas.drawPath()  (this is better than going through all offsets and drawing in between them) and also draw a circle in all of the offsets.

I hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This pub package provides a quick way to draw a smooth graph going through specific points - https://pub.dev/packages/smoothie

Answer (score 0):

When drawing lines using the `drawPath` method on `Canvas`, `strokeJoin` might be another property worth checking out from the `Paint` class.
Since it defaults to `StrokeJoin.miter`, changing it `StrokeJoin.round` did the trick for my use case.

```dart
class SmoothPainter extends CustomPainter {
  const SmoothPainter(this.path);

  final Path path;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.round
      ..strokeWidth = 25
      ..color = const Color(0xFFAABBCC);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(SmoothPainter oldDelegate) => path != oldDelegate.path;
}
```

From [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Paint/strokeJoin.html) -

> The kind of finish to place on the joins between segments.
>
> This applies to paths drawn when style is set to PaintingStyle.stroke, It does not apply to points drawn as lines with Canvas.drawPoints.
>
> Defaults to `StrokeJoin.miter`, i.e. sharp corners.

**Note:** The doc link also contains visuals to each `StrokeJoin` enum.